# Azure function publish deleted existing functions

Tags: azure-functions, publish

I have two different Azure Function projects in a Visual Studio solution. When I publish the second project to the same Azure Functions App in Azure, the functions that are already deployed get deleted. Is there any way for the functions to co-exist?

Thank you
Angelo

Comment: You need to use 1 project so the functions that exist on azure also exist on your project. Before deploying vscode gives a warning message that the deployment will override what is present on azure

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all the functions in a single Project in Visual Studio to deploy on azure and keep pre-deployed function. If your functions are not in the same project, new deployment overrides the previous deployment.

I have reproduced in my environment. I was also having same issue; pre-deployed function was getting deleted by new deployed function.
I have created two function one HTTP trigger name **"Httptrigger1"** and Time trigger **"Function1"**
and both are created in **Test** and **test2** folder respectively with same project name **"multiplefunction"** and deployed to my function **"publishmuliplefunctionon"** on Azure.
As shown below:
**Http trigger:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Time trigger:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*As you can see it has overridden the previous **Httptrigger1** function.*

To deploy new function without overriding you need to create new function in same project.
I have created new Httptrigger named **Function2 :**

[image]

***you can change name of the function in the bottom:***

[image]

***You can select your trigger and authorization:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**When you deploy using VS code, it gives you a warning message before deployment to Azure.**

[image]